# Portal users have no access to files (ContentVersion)

Tags: files, contentversion

I am displaying in my Experience Cloud portal images uploaded as `ContentVersion` files. Users can see images properly, but only when logged in to portal as "Log in to portal as user" button on their Contact record.

When logged in through login page, images won't display. I guess it is a problem with access settings, but I have not found any other privacy settings related to files than `ContentDocumentLink.Visibility`.

`ContentDocumentLink.Visibility` is set to `'AllUsers'` and `ContentVersion.SharingPrivacy` is set to `'N'`, which means Visible to Anyone With Record Access. Files are uploaded to records, on which OWD is set to Public Read Only, so they deffinietely do have access to parent records.

I have tried with the following URL versions:

- `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0680C000001Y2Dz?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER`
- `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=SVGZ&versionId=0680C000001Y2Dz`
- `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0680C000001Y2Dz`
- `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0680C000001Y2Dz`
- `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=0680C000001Y2Dz&operationContext=CHATTER`

And even

- `https://mysandbox.my.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=0680C000001Y2FH&operationContext=CHATTER`
- `https://mysandbox.my.salesforce.com/MyCommunity/s/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=0680C000001Y2FH&operationContext=CHATTER`

Neither worked.

I am displaying them in LWC using

````
<img src={imageURL} alt=""/>```
````

Comment: If it works via  "Log in to portal as user", this should be your clue that whatever happens during Login _and_ rendering of links ("displaying...portal images") is not correctly establishing or propagating user identity context.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: @identigral i updated my question. I know it's not correctly establishing or propagating user identity context but i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Check this link https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_files_on_records_visible_to_customers.htm&type=5

Comment: @SarojBera thanks, I am aware of that, as i said Visibility is set to AllUsers.

Comment: Is the `ShareType` set to `V`?